# Get the number of friends who liked a certain url

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I've been  struggling with fql queries and opengraph for almost a week and I didn't manage to find a solution regarding this. What I want is the number of friends who have liked a certain url. Just a number.

At some point i tried to retrieve all the user_ids of my friends and iterate through the friends_likes using a multi-query, but results were inconsistent.

I've tried numerous queries without success, please if there is some reference or some guidance on how to achieve this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate queries are not possible with both FQL and Graph API. So you need to count the results yourself.

You need to distinguish between URL Likes and Page Likes, because those are separate things! By querying "friends_likes", you'll receive Page Likes.

If you want to query which of your friends liked a certain URL, try this FQL query and replace YOUR_URL with your desired URL:

```
select user_id from url_like where url='YOUR_URL' and user_id in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```

If you want to query which of your friends like a certain Page, try this using the Page_ID (here CocaCola):

```
select uid from page_fan where page_id = 40796308305 and uid in (select uid2 from friend where uid1=me())
```

Comment: I have tried the first query which interests me but the result set is always blank

Comment: You need to have the "friends_likes" in the Access Token which you are using, have a look here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/

Comment: On facebook developers test console on their website I've selected all access checkboxes

Comment: Also under friends permissions? If so, it's possible that none of your friends liked the URL you specified as YOUR_URL!

Comment: All permisions are selected and I have a dummy friend account

Comment: Well, then you also need to like some URL and then test the same URL with the FWL query. To see if this Account has some URL Likes at all, try "select user_id from url_like where user_id = FRIEND_USER_ID"

Comment: I did like a url with a friend account